# Can't view Heroku logs - Cannot read property 'run' of undefined

Tags: python, git, heroku

I am attempting to deploy a python3 app to heroku. The app has some kind of error and isn't rendering (I see the generic error message in the browser) so I'm trying to troubleshoot via Heroku logs,  but I get this error instead of the log output.

```
C:\Users\Kate\AppData\Local\heroku\tmp\heroku-script-182282411:14
cmd.run(ctx)
   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kate\AppData\Local\heroku\tmp\heroku-script-
182282411:14:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:160:18)
    at node.js:445:3
```

This is on Windows 7 x86, I tried in both windows command prompt and Git Bash and got the same result. I installed the latest Heroku toolbelt with no change. Any thoughts on what to try next?

Comment: Just to confirm, this is the output from running `heroku logs`?  Do other heroku commands work, such as `heroku info -a <app name>`?

Comment: Yes, heroku info works and I can deploy just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I fully uninstalled heroku toolbelt including deleting the c:...\Heroku folder then reinstalled it and now it is working again. So I guess the first install didn't take.